# Tornado i18n csv files and Unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, internationalization, tornado

I'm working on a tornado (python 2.7) project and I'd like to provide it in multiple languages. 
I'm using tornado.locale to do that but I get a UnicodeDecodeError when using german umlauts in my csv file.

I'm loading translations like this:

```
translationsPath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "translations")
tornado.locale.load_translations(translationsPath)
```

In my csv file I have this (for example):

```
"Overview","Übersicht"
```

In my template:

```
{{ _("Overview") }}
```

which results in:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 18: invalid start byte

"Ü" should be covered by utf-8 so I don't get what isn't working.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Turns aut the file was broken. I guess Excel messed the encoding up.